# How to make each radiobutton unique from the others in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, radio-button

I have a window in Tkinter that looks like this:
[image]

When i click on a button in the first row, it stays. However, when i click on a button in the second row, it unselects the one i chose above.

I want it to be able to only select one option per row. Is there something I'm missing? When it's done, I want to be able to iterate over the rows and get the value of the boxes, but I'm not sure how to do that either.
The code for that section is:

```
for i in studentList:
    Label(left,text=i[0][::]+' ' + i[1][::],fg='black',bg='#dbdbdb',font=('Arial',11,'bold')).grid(row=counter,column=0,pady=13,sticky='news')
    P = Radiobutton(right,text='Present',bg='#56ab32',fg='black',value='P'+str(counter),indicatoron = 0,font=('Arial',12,'bold'))
    P.grid(row=counter,column=0,pady=10,padx=20,sticky='news')
    L = Radiobutton(right,text='Leave',bg='#e6a800',fg='white',indicatoron = 0,value='L'+str(counter),font=('Arial',12,'bold'))
    L.grid(row=counter,column=1,pady=10,padx=20,sticky='news')
    Radiobutton(right,text='Absent',bg='#bd2900',fg='white',indicatoron = 0,value='A'+str(counter),font=('Arial',12,'bold')).grid(row=counter,column=2,pady=10,padx=20,sticky='news')
    counter+=1
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Radiobuttons work by assigning two or more radiobuttons the same instance of one of tkinter's special variable objects -- usually`StringVar` or `IntVar`. This sharing of a variable is what makes a group of radiobuttons work as a set, since the variable can only hold a single value.

Because you aren't assigning a variable, tkinter is using a default variable which is the same for every button. Thus, all buttons are acting as a single set.

To make your code work, each row needs to use it's own instance of `StringVar`. It would look something like this:

```
vars = []
for i in studentList:
    var = StringVar()
    vars.append(var)
    ...
    Radiobutton(right, variable=var, ...)
    Radiobutton(right, variable=var, ...)
    Radiobutton(right, variable=var, ...)
    ...
```

With the above, you can get the choice of each row by getting the value of the variable for that row. For example, the first row would be `vars[0].get()`, the second row would be `vars[1].get()` and so on.

Comment: I can't begin to understand why this has a downvote. This is unquestionably the correct solution. <shrug>